Go compiler flag -trimpath not working completely
I have an issue where the -trimpath is not removing the GOPATH from the last line of the stacktrace.
Below is the snapshot of the stacktrace:
Apr 15 09:56:59 10-79-108-22 system-health[3923528]: [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x144efd2]
Apr 15 09:56:59 10-79-108-22 system-health[3923528]: goroutine 1 [running]:
Apr 15 09:56:59 10-79-108-22 system-health[3923528]: github.com/go-redis/redis.(*cmdable).HGetAll(0xc002cc78b0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
Apr 15 09:56:59 10-79-108-22 system-health[3923528]: github.com/go-redis/redis.(*cmdable).HGetAll(0xc002cc78b0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
Apr 15 09:56:59 10-79-108-22 system-health[3923528]:         github.com/go-redis/redis@v6.13.2+incompatible/commands.go:923 +0xd2
Apr 15 09:56:59 10-79-108-22 system-health[3923528]: controller/systemhealth.someOtherFunc(...)
Apr 15 09:56:59 10-79-108-22 system-health[3923528]:         controller/systemhealth/system_health.go:676
Apr 15 09:56:59 10-79-108-22 system-health[3923528]: controller/systemhealth.someFunction(...)
Apr 15 09:56:59 10-79-108-22 system-health[3923528]:         controller/systemhealth/system_health.go:680
Apr 15 09:56:59 10-79-108-22 system-health[3923528]: controller/systemhealth.ServiceInitialize()
Apr 15 09:56:59 10-79-108-22 system-health[3923528]:         controller/systemhealth/system_health.go:685 +0x6b
Apr 15 09:56:59 10-79-108-22 system-health[3923528]: main.main()
Apr 15 09:56:59 10-79-108-22 system-health[3923528]:         /home/hemant/dev/go/src/controller/go-controller.go:743 +0x231e

My GOPATH = /home/hemant/dev/go/src
My compiler flags while building are: -gcflags=-trimpath=$GOPATH -trimpath -asmflags=-trimpath=$GOPATH -trimpath
GOPATH should have been removed from the last line also.
Also side question: Is it possible to NOT expose directory path also and have mere filename ?

I see you also reported this on GitHub with more details: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/66849

Please check that your GOPATH is correct by changing the build command from ... go build ... to ... echo go build ... in order to print the command and check that it is correct. Based on the build command you posted on GitHub, it seems that you are trying to change GOPATH using env ... GOPATH=... but because of the way the shell expands variables it does not affect the -trimpath=$GOPATH parts, and they still refer to the previous GOPATH. If that's the case, then the solution is to change the build command to cd ... && export GOPATH=... && CC=gcc CXX=g++ go build ....

Aside: It might also be worth trying using just -trimpath, without -gcflags=... and -asmflags=....

The comments from the Go team member on GitHub concur. Post a comment (here or on GitHub) if the suggestions don't resolve the issue for you.

Thanks @tom, just plain simple -trimpath worked.

As per the comments, setting just -trimpath without -gcflags=... and -asmflags=.... fixed the issue (which was probably due to a mix-up with GOPATH).
